# Navigating records in a form based on a criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that is bound to a table that holds data on projects. There are several statuses that the project can be in:

New
In Progress
On Hold
Complete
Cancelled
Progressed

The first 3 are "Open", the later 3 are "Closed"

I would like to be able to add some navigation buttons (next/prev) that look for the next/prev record based on a drop down that contains "Open", "Closed" and "All". Only records that meet this criteria will appear when using the navigation.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have you considered filtering before navigation?

Comment: You know when you have one of those weeks that everything you know just disappears? Yeh. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

The easiest solution is to make a **filter**, as suggested by JohnHC.
You can use a combobox in which you select "Open", "Close", "All".

By selecting a value in the combo (or listbox) you can set the filter (e.g. "Open" --> Status = "New" OR Status = "In Progress" OR Status = "Hold").

The filtering can be done dynamically on the form setting via VBA the .FilterBy condition and FilterByOn = TRUE in the combobox after update event.

**SOLUTION 2**

You can also think about a solution in which when you press the navigation button you **search** for the next record with desired status **and** the you **move** to that record.
It's more tricky and sincerely I can't see any advantage but it depends on what you are imaging for your database.